# Bootstrap 4 : Vertically Align Navigation Links when Logo Increases the Navbar Height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

I'm new to the Bootstrap 4 framework, but even after reading all the documentation and all the existing B4 questions on StackOverFlow, I'm still a bit stuck.

In my navigation bar, I inserted a SVG logo that has a height and width of 50px. This automatically makes the navbar taller. I have not adjusted any CSS for this, it is simply the logo that is forcing the navbar height to increased.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@yield('title')</title>
    <link rel="import" href="elements.html">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/app.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="navbar navbar-light navbar-fixed-top bd-faded">
        <div class="clearfix hidden-sm-up">
            <button class="navbar-toggler pull-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
                    &#9776;
                </button>
            <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">
                <img src="/images/brand.svg" alt="Logo">
                <span>Bootstrap</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-xs" id="navbar">
            <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">
                <img src="/images/brand.svg" alt="Logo">
                <span>Bootstrap</span>
            </a>
            <nav class="nav navbar-nav">
                <div class="nav-item nav-link"><a href="#">Link 1</a></div>
                <div class="nav-item nav-link"><a href="#">Link 2</a></div>
                <div class="nav-item nav-link"><a href="#">Link 3</a></div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/vendor.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my Custom CSS:

```
.navbar-brand {
    font-size: 22px;
    img {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 8px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
    }
}
```

I'd like the navigation links which is *link1, link2, & link3* to be vertically align to the title which is *Bootstrap*.

Thanks You in Advance

Comment: Do you have this caption "Bootstrap" under the logo or only logo?

Comment: @makshh I have both logo + title which is currently "Bootstrap" ... it located to the right of the logo

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you can remove top and bottom padding from links and add height and line-height to it. Also remove padding from `.navbar-brand`.

Just add this CSS:

```
.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0;
}
.navbar-nav .nav-link {
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

### **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrbbed)**

Comment: This was also my first solution until I realized it would be a "hack" caused by by "malformed" markup, or markup used against the B4 intention - I mainly have responsiveness in mind.

Comment: Agreed with the comment above, I'd like to avoid the additional css styles.

Comment: Thanks for this. Playing around with the bottom padding for the nav-link helped to align the links to a specific height on my brand (which is a logo, not text).

Comment: setting height and line height does the trick

Answer (score 16):

I ran into a similar situation where I'd like to vertically align my nav-items.

**Step 1:** Add the classes `d-lg-flex align-items-center` to your `.navbar-nav` parent element. This ensures that you can align child items using flex-utilities

**Step 2:** Add the `h-100` class to each child `nav-item`. Nav-item has no defined height that I'm aware of. With `nav-item`'s defined height, it will follow the flex rules set above by `align-items-center`.

**Step 3:** Please check my external links in my codepen because the navbar requires additional js.

Here is a working example of vertically centered nav-items
https://codepen.io/b3bold/pen/rvMwzN

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md p-3 mb-2 navbar-light bg-white text-dark">   
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/snRuy.jpg" />
  </a>

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto text-center w-100 justify-content-between ml-lg-0 d-lg-flex align-items-center">
      <div class="nav-item h-100"><a class="nav-link" href="#">RandomLink</a></div>
      <div class="nav-item h-100"><a class="nav-link"href="#">Some Really Long Link as an Example of Vertical </a></div>
      <div class="nav-item h-100"><a class="nav-link" href="#">RandomLink</a></div>
      <div class="nav-item h-100"><a class="nav-link" href="#">RandomLink</a></div>
      <div class="nav-item h-100"><a class="nav-link" href="#">RandomLink</a></div>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using Bootstrap 4.5.0. For me the following did the trick (I had to add mt-2, in addition to what @Alexander Romero mentioned above) :

```
        <li class="nav-item dropdown align-items-center mt-2"><select class="dropdown" id="changeAccentColor">
            <option value="">Theme</option>
            <option value="">Default</option>
            <option value="#F5FFFA">Mint</option>
            <option value="#32CD32">Lime</option>
            <option value="#008080">Teal</option>
            <option value="#DCDCDC">Gray</option>
            <option value="#FFC0CB">Pink</option>
            <option value="#F5F5F5">Smoky</option>
        </select></li>
```

Now my custom dropdown stays vertically aligned to the height I have set for nav even though I zoom in 400-500%. It works flawlessly. Hope someone will find it useful to fit their need.

Answer (score -3):

Try this.

```
 <header class="navbar navbar-default navbar-top">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <!-- Stat Toggle Nav Link For Mobiles -->
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                        </button>
                        <!-- End Toggle Nav Link For Mobiles -->
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                            <h3>Bootstrap</h3>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-right">
                       <!-- Start Navigation List -->
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li> <a href="#">Link 1</a> </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a> </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- End Navigation List -->
                    </div>
                </div>
      </header>
```

Comment: is this for Bootstrap 4, asking cause i didn't see nav-item and nav-link classes located inside the navbar-nav